# Find pandas column name using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find pandas columns using a list of strings, but I want to find columns even if it contains part of the string. Now if the column name is 'TVD' and I have 'tv' in my list, I want it to be found. The reason is I want to drop these columns and bring them back to the first column. This is my current code but I'm only able to find the exact column name. Let's say the column name is 'TVD (feet)', then I'll be having a problem.

```
df = sts.read_df(dataset)
depth_names_lower = ['tvd', 'tvdss', 'md']
depth_names_upper = [depth.upper() for depth in depth_names_lower]
depth_names = depth_names_lower + depth_names_upper

tvd_cols = [col for col in df.columns if depth_names in col]
cols = list(df.columns)
for depth in tvd_cols:
    cols.pop(cols.index(depth))
df = df[tvd_cols+cols]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regexp to find the target columns, as `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to ignore case.

```
pattern = '|'.join(depth_names_lower)
cond = df.columns.str.contains(pattern, regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
cols = df.columns[cond]
df[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to check if depth_names which is a list in contained in col which is a string. This will always return False. You want to do an individual check of each string in depth_names to see if that is a substring of col. One way to do that is to use another list contraction:

```
tvd_cols = [col for col in df.columns if any([d in col for d in depth_names])]
```

The inner-contraction will return a list of booleans. "any" evaluates to a single boolean, True if and only if at least one of the list is True.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can consider accepting it as a correct answer by the button to the left of the answer. @ArivinRaj

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.